# How to fix Alarm subroutine to work in Assembly to work in PIC microcontroller

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip

I have a project to complete which is almost complete with just the alarm not buzzing if a wrong password is entered. This is my alarm subroutine.

This will be used for PIC16F877

```
HOT:
     BTFSC PORTA,7
     CALL  BEEP
     BTFSC PORTA,6
     CALL  BEEP
     BTFSC PORTA,5
     CALL  BEEP
     BTFSC PORTA,4
     CALL  BEEP
     BCF   STATUS, 2     ;Return to menu check
     CALL  GETPW
     XORLW '#'
     BTFSS STATUS, 2
     GOTO  HOT
     BCF   STATUS, 2
     RETURN

     BEEP:  
     MOVLW B'11111111' 
     MOVWF PORTC
     CLRF PORTB 
     GOTO BEEP
     RETURN
```

Comment: Any help guys? Can't seem to figure it out

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do here? If you just turn on all the bits in PORTC and turn off all the bits on PORTB, does this activate your buzzer? If that is the case your code will be buzzing forever, but you claim that it is not buzzing ...

I think we need some more info to be of any more help.

Comment: BTW. if my guess above is correct, and the code is setting the ports correctly (even though BEEP never returns) then it is more likely that you have set PORTC and/or PORTB to be inputs and not outputs ...

Answer (score 0):

The subroutine `BEEP` is an endless loop and will never reach the `RETURN` statement.

```
 BEEP:  
 MOVLW B'11111111' 
 MOVWF PORTC
 CLRF PORTB 
 GOTO BEEP        ;jump back to BEEP label -> endlessloop 
 RETURN
```